# Why is this edge loop disappearing when I zoom in?

Tags: mesh

I'm in [Part 3 of the Donut Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqJx5TJyhes). We have used a deformed torus as the body of the donut, then superimposed a copy of that as the icing. We used the Solidify Modifier to give the icing thickness, and then we hid that modifier in Edit Mode (by turning off "Display modifier in Edit mode") so we could see the mesh of the icing. The result of all that, as shown in the tutorial video, is this:

[image]

My result looks a lot like that if I'm zoomed way out:

[image]

In both of the above pictures, there are six latitudinal edge loops.

But if I zoom way in, the bottom loop disappears. It doesn't disappear cleanly, but there are little, straggly, lines extending below the fifth loop:

[image]

If I zoom back out part way, part of the bottom loop reappears, and there are disconnected vertices and longer straggly lines extending below the fifth loop.:

[image]

That description remains the same if I select the entire icing mesh:

[image]

What it looks like is happening is that there are six complete loops, but the bottom loop gets partially or completely hidden when I'm zoomed in to any extent. This is a problem because the next step is that I'm supposed to make the icing droop down at various spots around the equator by selecting vertices in the bottom loop and dragging them down. It doesn't seem that I can select and drag the bottom vertices in places where I can't see them.

Have I done something wrong that is causing this problem, or is there something I need to do make that bottom loop visible at all zoom levels?

Comment: The edge loop is hidden by geometry because it is slightly inside the donut. When geometry is very close together but far away from the viewpoint so that this difference is very small, Blender sometimes has problems calculating which is in front and therefore visible. And it seems (don't know if that is true) that the geometry which you are currently editing gets preferred to be shown, probably because it is the active geometry in that moment.